# Apiary multiple blueprint file into one api

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Hi I am using Apiary to maintain a documentation for my REST API, as our code base is growing our API documentation is getting bigger and bigger. It is becoming very difficult to put all our API inside the single blueprint file, is there any way we can properly organize them into multiple files and show them inside apiary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is an undocumented way (it's ugly, but it works): if you are connected with github, you can create a file called `apiary.manifest` in the root of your repository.

Inside it, you can put newline-separated list of relative paths that are concatenated in that order and shown on your apiary subdomain.

Please note, however, that apiary currently doesn't provide a good way to edit this in the apiary editor. Should you save it there, you'll just get concatenated version saved as `apiary.apib` back in your repo (this is why it's undocumented).

You'll have to use your editor to edit the blueprint further, i.e. sublime with [apiary plugin](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-sublime-plugin).

Comment: Do you thinbk you will ever support it with the cli client ? thanks :)

Comment: @mojzis definitely; we just want to have better way of configuring the blueprint tooling than the manifest file.

Comment: great ! looking forward :)